# combine tuples to form lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

```
data= [('a ', 1), ('b ', 3), ('a ', 4), ('b', 2),]
```

How do get two lists with the first element of tuple as the list name and the second as values?

```
a= [1,4]
b= [3,2]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in your previous question, you shouldn't try to change the name you're binding something to.  [The left-hand side of `something = 3`, I mean.]  It causes nothing but trouble.  You could use a `dict` instead, and a `defaultdict` would make things handy:

```
>>> data= [('a ', 1), ('b ', 3), ('a ', 4), ('b', 2),]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in data:
...     d[k.strip()].append(v)
...     
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [3, 2]})
```

After which

```
>>> d['a']
[1, 4]
>>> d['b']
[3, 2]
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks DSM. The last bit really helped as I already had the defaultdict object but did not know how to do numpy ops on the values. Now I can.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the keys in your example have some extra whitespace, I'm using `strip`:

```
In [11]: [x[1] for x in data if x[0].strip() == 'a']
Out[11]: [1, 4]

In [12]: [x[1] for x in data if x[0].strip() == 'b']
Out[12]: [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lev's answer is what you look for. Additionally, ou can group by an arbitrary key:

```
grouped = defaultdict(list)
[grouped[key].append(value) for key, value in data]
```

By the way, [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is one of many built-in types  worth examining. There are many types and functions that may solve your daily problems. Check at least [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [functools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionary here, instead of creating multiple variables.

```
In [14]: data= [('a ', 1), ('b ', 3), ('a ', 4), ('b',2),]

In [15]: dic={}

In [16]: for k,v in data:
   ....:     dic.setdefault(k.strip(),[]).append(v)
   ....:     

In [18]: dic
Out[18]: {'a': [1, 4], 'b': [3, 2]}
```